# Data binding expression not compiling

Tags: android, data-binding

I'm trying out the new data binding library. I have a weird issue where binding the `visibility` property is not compiling.

This is a simplified version of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

    <variable
        name="header"
        type="com.example.EmailHeader" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout ... >

        <TextView
            ...
            android:text="@{header.senderName ?? header.senderAddress}"
            android:visibility="@{header.hasAttachment ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

I get the follow message when compiling:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>     ****/ data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. View is missing it

Everything compiles (and works!) when I remove the `android:visiblity` declaration.

I don't see what I'm missing here

Comment: Can you share your EmailHeader class?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Inside of the data tag you need to also add:

```
<import type="android.view.View" />
```

Comment: it should, the error clearly states that "View" does not have a definition. importing `android.view.View` should fix it and if not, please share the new error and updated layout code.

Comment: I had the same issue and this worked for me. IMHO, should be the accepted answer. Thanks bwhite!

Comment: I faced the same issue for my Handler, which I didn't declared in <data>. After declaring my handler it got fixed.

Comment: "the error clearly states".. Clear if you know what the answer is maybe. Otherwise it is a terribly written error message. Read to me like the view was missing a user-defined type (whatever that might have meant).

Comment: this fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

Problem persisted despite adding `<import type="android.view.View" />` to my data tag.Finally found the error to be caused by a mismatch of my variable name and object of my POJO class.

This was my data tag:

```
<data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable
            name="employee"
            type="com.example.Employee"/>
    </data>
```

and I was using:

```
<TextView
        ...
        android:text="@{user.lastName}" />
```

instead of:

```
<TextView
        ...
        android:text="@{employee.lastName}" />
```

Forgot to change it after copying code from documentation.
Look out for mistakes like this which are hard to detect for newbies to DataBinding

Comment: not just newbies, this is a common pattern, that we're now going to have to deal with.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the exact same error which was caused by the fact that the POJO object was in a library project.

Just upate the build.gradle of the library to enable databinding as well as in the main project:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```